# How do you find matching numbers in column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have A and B columns in Excel, if the number is in both the columns, I want to write note "Exist" in columns C automatically, in the row that the value appears in column B.

Example:

```
A   |  B | C 
1   |  2 | Not Exist
3   |  4 | Not Exist
5   |  1 | Exist
6   |  7 | Not Exist
```

Comment: Formula Based questions are not OFFTOPIC(for SuperUser) and belong to StackOverlow as per this [RECENT](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199823/slight-amendment-to-close-reason) post in Meta. One may however close this question, using the `Questions asking for code must demonstrate...` reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the simple formula `COUNTIF`

Put this in `C1`

`=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)>0,"Exists","Doesn't Exist")`

[image]