# How to check in excel if a cell doesn't contain a list of values

Tags: excel

let's say i have a cell in excel with Text, and i have another column of text values. I want to check if that cell contains any of the values in the column.

How to?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you find matching numbers in column in Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899854/how-do-you-find-matching-numbers-in-column-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googled some more and found a solution

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER((SEARCH("*"&B1:B10,A1)))),TRUE,FALSE)

returns true if A1 contains any of the strings in B1 to B10

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to check whether cell `B1` contains any of the values in the column `A`

Then you could use

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)
```

Comment: doesn't solve my problem. I need to check that the text CONTAINS any of the column values and not just matching them.

Comment: @user2979894 how these both things are different? this formula will give you `1` when the text CONTAINS column values, otherwise returns `0`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this **array-entered** formula should do it, returning TRUE if a word in ColumnOfTextValues can be found in MyCell.

```
=OR(COUNTIF(MyCell,"*"&ColumnOfTextValues&"*"))
```

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces {...} around the formula.